# A set-family where in each coloring, at least one set is single-colored

Tags: co.combinatorics

Given an integer $k$, we would like a family of $k$-sized sets such that, in any coloring of the items with two colors, at least one set is single-colored. What is the smallest number of sets we need?

Obviously $s(1)=1$, and it is easy to prove that $s(2)=3$. What about $k\geq 3$?

As a side-question: I often run into similar questions regarding set-families, and I feel I am missing some background to approach them. What is a good textbook to study about such problems?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_B

Comment: "I often run into similar questions regarding set-families, and I feel I am missing some background to approach them." Maybe Ian Anderson, *Combinatorics of finite sets*, and Konrad Engel, *Sperner theory*, are helpful (though none of them studies Property B).

Comment: $s(k)\leq (2k-1$ choose $k)$:
Indeed, by the pigeonhole principle, any $2$-coloring of a set of $n=2k-1$ objects will contain a single-coloured subset of size $k$, hence if you picked *all* subsets of size $k$ one of them must be single-coloured as required.

It is easy to see that there is no solution from $n<2k-1$ objects, and that ($2k-1$ choose $k$) is the best one can do from $n=2k-1$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier this is very helpful, thank you.